# ELMAH like package / tool for class library to log exceptions

Tags: c#, elmah, error-logging

I am using ELMAH for my webapi error logging. Wondering if there is a ready made solution for class library as well? My ServiceFacade layer is a c# class library and i want to log exceptions

Answer (score 1):

you can use it my friend:

```
      try
        {
            // your code in here
        }
        catch (Exception ert)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(ert));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH isn't tied to web applications only. I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.elmah.io/how-to-log-errors-to-elmah-programmatically/) about that last year but in essence, you'll need to log the errors manually but without a HTTP context:

```
ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
```